# Testing nested components in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have some problems with testing events for nested components.
This is how my component tree look like:

```
- ModalComponent (Stateful with value for Input and update handler)
- - ModalType (stateless, passes value and update down to input)
- - - Input (stateless)
```

I have the value state and the handler for updating my value in my ModalComponent. This information just passed down through `ModalType` to my `Input` element via props.

I have tried to mount my `ModalComponent` with enzyme, find my input and simulate a change on the element. But this did not work.

What is the best strategy to test nested component when the handler and state are n parents components above?

**EDIT**
I have created a lean demo setup of my component in a separate blank react project

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    inputs: {
      machineName: 'Empty'
    }
  }

  onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    let updatedState = null
    console.log(e.target.value, e.target.id);

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'machineName':
        updatedState = { ...this.state.inputs, machineName: e.target.value }
        this.setState({inputs: updatedState})
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ModalType onChange={this.onChangeHandler} value={this.state.inputs}></ModalType>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ModalType = (props) => {
  return <Input onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value.machineName}></Input>
}

const Input = (props) => (
  <input id="machineName" onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value}></input>
)
```

My testing script

```
test('should handle change on input', () =>{
  const wrapper = mount(<App/>)
  wrapper.setState({inputs: { machineName: 'Empty' }})
  wrapper.find('input').simulate('focus')
  wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: '123'}})
  wrapper.update()
  // fails
  expect(wrapper.state().inputs.machineName).toEqual('123')
  // fails too
  expect(wrapper.find('input').props().value).toEqual('123')
  })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the sample from your test file ? Accodring to my limited knowledge of Enzyme this should work with something like `input.simulate('change', event)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const wrapper = mount(<ModalComponent />);
const input = wrapper.find('input');
const event  = {target: {value: 'testValue'}};
input.simulate('change', event);
```

The code above is a working example of how to simulate a change event on your input.

**Edit**

Your event is not correct. Since your handler is doing something only if the target id is machineName, you need to add that id to your mock event.

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: '123', id: 'machineName'}})
```

Comment: This is the way that I have tried. And it didn't work for me

Comment: Looks like you are missing the id in your fake event. I have edited my answer.